AWS Route 53 not showing my domain on AWS console
I am new to AWS, I am trying to create cname for my cloudfront. I am following below tutorial to do the same but on clicking "create record in Route 53" an domain name is not showing up. Is their any thing I am missing ?

Expectation

Current Behaviour



Have you checked you Route53 if the record was created? You are showing the ACM console with filters that check if there are still pending validation. Go to Route53 and check your hosted zone.

@TsalTroser No hosted zones are there. In tutorial also he didn't refer to any hosted zone.

Do you have the domain productinfoservice.com in your Route53 that you use in this? Because the option create record in Route 53 will create an entry in the hosted zone of the domain you use.
